# Data Loss Issue Replace Text and Put sql Processor

Tags: oracle, hadoop, apache-nifi, hdf

We have created a flow in nifi,

-- From hive(selecthiveql) we are getting 4257 records

-- based on output of selecthiveql we are passing the data based on attribute to replaceText Processor with the insert query into it and passing it to putsql processor

-- when data is being is loading into the oracle, we are getting data loss. we were able to load only 4000 out of 4257 records.

I have attached the screenshot as well. Please have a look at it.

If anyone help us in this scenario would be very helpful.
[image]

Comment: Do you think it might possibly be something to do with the "failed t update database due to a failed batch update" message? How are we supposed to guess why that failed?

Comment: 4000 is a suspiciously round number. Is some kind of loop with a counter involved?

Comment: What happens to the `failure` and `retry` outputs from PutSQL?  Can you route all the outputs separately to make them more visible, maybe to LogAttribute processors?  That might help you reconcile the count of records.

Comment: @priyanka You need to check query for insert rows by put the failure relationship into any processor.Just open content view and copy that query into SQL Server.If that query runs in SQL Server then NiFi PutSQL should run